# How do I get the real-time position of SCNNode?

Tags: scenekit

After `[node.physicsBody applyForce:force impulse:YES]`, the `node.position` will still be in the initial position. How to obtain the position after the force?

Comment: The physical location of the node has changed. But `node.position` is still the initial value.

Comment: Suggest having a look at the [`presentationNode` property of `SCNNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408030-presentationnode)

Comment: Thank you. I see.